# Telethon doesn't retrieve last messages from the chat

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, data-retrieval

I have this code:

```py
messages = []
async for message in client.iter_messages(chat):
    messages.append(message)
    if len(messages) >= 10:  # change this number to retrieve more or less messages
        break
```

Previously it worked good and the code retrieved last messages from the chat. But since 5 of May it stopped to retrieve last messages. Now the results look like.

But i didn't change anything in the code and didn't update library or something else. Why the code doesn't retrieve the last messages?

Please help me to understand what is wrong here. I just need to retrieve last messages from telegram chat.

Comment: Now results look like:
Chat "Name of the chat"

2023-05-05 11:14:40+00:00

2023-05-05 08:53:51+00:00

2023-05-05 08:53:22+00:00

2023-05-05 08:53:07+00:00

2023-05-05 08:52:21+00:00

Comment: So there is no last days after 5 of May there

Comment: Make sure the chat is the one you expect. If you haven't upgraded the library, the behavior from Telegram may have changed, or the chat may be different.